# LazyInitializationException and NonUniqueObjectException solution with FetchType.LAZY

Tags: java, hibernate, session

If I have a class Mother which contains a list of Kid and I want to Lazily load the Kid list with FetchType.LAZY, how can I structure my DAOs?

Currently if I get the objects from the DAO and don't close the session I get tons of

> org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the
>   same identifier value was already associated with the session

because it happens that sessions end up having different instances of the same Object.

If I however zealously close the session in the DAO I end up getting detached objects and the first time I try to access one of the lazily loaded objects with something like:

```
List<Kid> kidList = mother.getKids();
kidList.add(new Kid());
```

I get a

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
>   a collection of role: Mother.kids, could not initialize proxy - no
>   Session

The only solutions I happened to see around are:

1. not using DAOs and adding the open() and close() session calls directly in the code with the risk of forgetting closing one session.
2. abusing FetchType.EAGER here and there to solve issues
3. avoiding accessing the lazily loaded objects inside a detached object and using yet another DAO method to fetch the kids, something like KidDao.getKidsofMother(Long motherId).
4. using Session.merge(mother) to reattach the detached object and then accessing the collection.

Isn't there some elegant solution to this?

Comment: There is problem with your mapping probably. Show database structure and mapping.

Comment: Your initial approach is a standard one and you should use it. You need to find the cause for `NonUniqueObjectException`.

Comment: There isn't a better solution to the LazyInitializationException problem. It all depend by some considerations, example questions are how big are objects and collections, where you are exposing them (webview, swing gui, batch jobs?)

Comment: @DraganBozanovic Do you mean session should not be closed from DAO but left open? I am currently closing all sessions in the DAOs and detaching objects and solving with solution #3, which is quicker. What do you think?

Comment: @fantarama I am working with these object in a Swing GUI, collections are quite complex so Lazy load is a must.

Comment: As I already said, I think your top priority is to find out the cause of `NonUniqueObjectException`. That bug may still be around there, even with your workarounds. Regarding the third approach, to me it seems unnecessary and defeats the purpose and benefits of ORM.

Comment: with complex objects the use of generic getter like getMotherById isn't the better solutions, you need specialized methods that fetch all the necessary properties like getMotherAndKids(). In my opinion dealing with session can only expose you to other issues